# c# XMPP does not connect

Tags: c#, xmpp

i want to learn XMPP using c#.net in windows 7 so i downlod agsXMPP library  and jspon , and i write the following code just for test but i can't send informtion :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using agsXMPP;
using agsXMPP.protocol.client;
using agsXMPP.Collections;
using agsXMPP.protocol.iq.roster;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1

{
    class Program
    {
    static void xmpp_OnLogin(object sender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Logged In");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Login");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("JID: ");
        string JID_Sender = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Password: ");
        string Password = Console.ReadLine();

        Jid jidSender = new Jid(JID_Sender);
        XmppClientConnection xmpp = new XmppClientConnection(jidSender.Server);

        xmpp.Open(jidSender.User, Password);
        xmpp.OnLogin += new ObjectHandler(xmpp_OnLogin);


        Presence p = new Presence(ShowType.chat, "Online");
        p.Type = PresenceType.available;
        xmpp.Send(p);

    }


}
```

}

i enter my id (just created for test )
usernme : belkacemsend@jabber.org

here is the output :

```
Exception:Thrown: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." (System.NullReferenceException)
A System.NullReferenceException was thrown: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."


Exception:Caught: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." (System.NullReferenceException)
A System.NullReferenceException was caught: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."


Exception:Thrown: "A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied" (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)
A System.Net.Sockets.SocketException was thrown: "A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied"


Exception:Caught: "A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied" (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)
A System.Net.Sockets.SocketException was caught: "A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you need to wait OnLogin will be raised

```
xmpp.Open(jidSender.User, Password);
xmpp.OnLogin += new ObjectHandler(xmpp_OnLogin);

// Wait here

Presence p = new Presence(ShowType.chat, "Online");
p.Type = PresenceType.available;
xmpp.Send(p);
```

This article on codeproject.com has solution for this [Creating a Jabber Client using the agsXMPP Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21267/Creating-a-Jabber-Client-using-the-agsXMPP-Library), not the best but it is good for start.

```
bool isLoggedIn = false;
xmpp.OnLogin += (sender) => { isLoggedIn = true; };
xmpp.Open(jidSender.User, Password);

while (isLoggedIn == false) 
{ 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); 
}

Presence p = new Presence(ShowType.chat, "Online");
p.Type = PresenceType.available;
xmpp.Send(p);
```